# usage of self.client.get() vs self.browser.get()

Tags: django, tdd

I'm working through this book about TDD with Django.
I get different behaviour from using `self.client.get('/')` and different one from using `self.browser.get('/localhost:8000')` seemingly they look
the same but getting different behaviour.

```
class FirstTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver'))

    def test_home_page_returns_correct_html(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
```

Can anybody explain what's happening here ?

Comment: I presume that test is actually inheriting from `django.test.TestCase`, otherwise `self.client` wouldn't exist.

Comment: Yeah I just realised I used self.client.get() in functional tests which is why it doesn't work. It supposed to be in Django tests. That's the distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are two different things.

`self.client`, is the built-in Django test client. This isn't a real browser, and doesn't even make real requests. It just constructs a Django HttpRequest object and passes it through the request/response process - middleware, URL resolver, view, template - and returns whatever Django produces. It won't parse that response at all, or render it, and won't make other requests driven by the HTML for assets etc.

But `webdriver.Chrome` is an actual real browser, ie Chrome. Webdriver fires up a headless version of Chrome and drives it to request your web pages. They go through actual HTTP requests and then *render in the browser* the response; just like a real browser, if the HTML includes links to JS or CSS it will request them and then render them as well.

Comment: The only note I'd make is that the `request` object in a Django `Client` is a `WSGIRequest` object, not an `HttpRequest` object (see the source: `return WSGIRequest(self._base_environ(**request))`). That tripped me a few times when writing assertions and thinking I was dealing with a `HttpRequest`.