# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I'm getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'` error when trying to run this code `self.client.get("/")`. Test running in Docker on Windows 10 machine. Other simple model tests are running good, just like the application itself. Also tried running this test in another project, and there wasn't any problems. Feel free to ask for more information if needed.
The whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/app/tests/test.py", line 5, in test_test
    resp = self.client.get("/")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 836, in get
    response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 424, in get
    return self.generic(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 541, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 805, in request
    response = self.handler(environ)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 140, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 61, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 105, in __init__
    self.add_files(self.static_root, prefix=self.static_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 107, in add_files
    self.update_files_dictionary(root, prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 119, in update_files_dictionary
    self.add_file_to_dictionary(url, path, stat_cache=stat_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 130, in add_file_to_dictionary
    static_file = self.get_static_file(path, url, stat_cache=stat_cache)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 202, in get_static_file
    self.add_cache_headers(headers, path, url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 223, in add_cache_headers
    if self.immutable_file_test(path, url):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 177, in immutable_file_test
    static_url = self.get_static_url(name_without_hash)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/whitenoise/middleware.py", line 200, in get_static_url
    return staticfiles_storage.url(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 266, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 496, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 419, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 25, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit(".", 1)
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

The whole test file:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestTest(TestCase):
    def test_test(self):
        resp = self.client.get("/")
```

docker-compose.yml file (all secure data is only for local development):

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9999:9999
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: blog
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 7895
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

All packages are up to date, using Python 3.11.2 and Django 4.1.7.
Settings.py file in case you will need it:

```
"""
Django settings for blogapp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""


from pathlib import Path
import os

from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "0").lower() in ["true", "t", "1"]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS").split(" ")
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = os.getenv("CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS").split(" ")


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "app.apps.AppConfig",
    "tinymce",
    "storages",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]


ROOT_URLCONF = "blogapp.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR.joinpath("templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "blogapp.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config()}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


TINYMCE_JS_URL = "https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/jys86spz5w4zp7jbfbr16eorvcw4sx1j2yg6q26namjws4do/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = Path(BASE_DIR).joinpath("upload")
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"

# S3 Bucket
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = os.getenv("DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE")
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = os.getenv("AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE", "0").lower() in ["true", "t", "1"]
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = os.getenv("AWS_DEFAULT_ACL")
STATICFILES_STORAGE = os.getenv("STATICFILES_STORAGE")
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv("AWS_S3_REGION_NAME")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the traceback, it seems that `settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` is None.
It seems you're getting it from a dotenv. Are you sure it is defined inside and your dotenv is found ?

Comment: You are right! For some reason, when I'm executing commands in Django shell running Docker, the file with environment variables is not importing. Because of that, I also added environment variables to my Docker file, but forgot about S3 bucket variables. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem you are having is that the response has not fully completed when you are trying to parse it, or the internal buffering is still waiting for more data if it does not know the size being returned.

I will usually fix this myself by using a JSON object to fetch the response with, as it uses it's internal class functions to do the HTTP housekeeping and buffering, and will easily give me the response object without worrying about buffering or testing for the end of the response myself.

In your case, it sounds like using the "Selenium Webdriver" may be one solution to this, there is a basic example here that you can see that should illustrate how to make the change - [usage of self.client.get() vs self.browser.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425954/usage-of-self-client-get-vs-self-browser-get)

***Alternatively Using JSON.loads():***

Below is some code that I copied from a project of mine showing usage of the JSON.loads() method, which may be simpler to use and does not require a web driver, it has solved this same problem for me.  In my case I use authentication to fetch data from a URL but you may be able to just leave that part out if you do not require it, here is the basic pseudocode:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib.parse
import json

post_data = json.dumps({"id": rpc_id, "method": method, "params": params}).encode()
auth = base64.encodebytes((RPC_USER + ":" + RPC_PASS).encode()).decode().strip()

request = urllib.request.Request("THE_URL_TO_READ_FROM", post_data, {"Authorization": "Basic {:s}".format(auth)})

    with urllib.request.urlopen(request) as f:

        response = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: The other answer to this question helped me, and I didn't test your solution, but I want to thank you for your answer. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.